# Solutions of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm studying about linear equations and I've stumbled upon a problem

I have an equation of the type $Ax = b$ where $A$ is a matrix, $x$ is a vector of unknown variables, and $b$ is a vector of the right side of the equations as given:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}4 & -3 & -2 & 2 \\-5& 5 & 1 & 1\\4 & 0 & -5 &2  \end{bmatrix} \\
b = \begin{bmatrix} 12 \\ -3 \\ 15 \end{bmatrix}
$$
And I used the Gauss Elimination to get to:

$$
[A|b] = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -17 & | -50\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -14 & |-42\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -14 & |-43  \end{bmatrix}
$$
But I'm having trouble writing down the solutions. Am i right that because I have 1 free column I will import a new parameter for example `t` and say $x_4 = t$ and express all the other variables using this parameter?

For example
$$
x_3 = 14t - 43\\
x_2 = 14t - 42\\
x_1 = 17t - 50
$$

Thank you a lot!

Comment: have you studied rank of a matrix ?

Comment: yes, rank(A) = number of pivots = 3 ( in this case)

Comment: since rank(ab)=rank(a) =3<(number of unknowns (n)=4). there will be infinite solns. what you did is right.